# Intellisense and navigation to references and definitions not working in VS2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, symbols, project-reference

**WARNING: I have posted this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/17rg467/intellisense_and_navigation_to_references_and/) a few weeks ago but never got a response.**

I have obtained a large .NET solution from a third-party, and I'm having the following issues with it:

- *Right click > Go to Definition* for a symbol imported from a namespace defined either in a `PackageReference` or `ProjectReference` results in the following popup:

[image]

- *Right click > Find all references* for a symbol belonging to a referenced namespace (DLL, project or NuGet package) yields no results, only the following information message in the "Find References" pane

[image]

- Intellisense does not work for symbols belonging to referenced namespaces. They are simply not highlighted:

All the above features work fine for symbols defined in the System namespace or the current namespace. Other solutions on my local machine do not exhibit this behavior and work fine. Things I have tried:

- Setting *Tools > Options > TextEditor > C# > Advanced > Run background code analysis for* to *Entire Solution* as well as
- Enabling CodeLens
- Deleting the `.vs` folder
- Cleaning and Rebuilding, both of which succeed but don't fix the issues I've described above.

None of these things have worked, so I'm beginning to think something more fundamental is going wrong *with this particular solution*. I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with it. What could cause symbols to not get recognized for a solution in Visual Studio 2022? How can I further isolate the root cause of the problem?

Comment: From where did you press F12? Also did you try creating a new solution/project and copy the files over and see if it has the same issue? Also maybe try with VS Code and see if it works?

Comment: Also since it's been many days since you posted the question I assume it's probably not the case but, did you try restarting your PC?

Comment: Please not only remove the .vs folder, but also remove the bin and obj folder. Regenerate all of them.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT removing the `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilding completely fails the build. The predominant error is CS0006. That's interesting to note. I will look into the build properties today.

Comment: This issue seems more related to the project/solution itself, reproduce is hard without more info of it.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I totally understand, but the purpose of my question is more like "How do I narrow this down to figure out the root cause." I understand that without a minimal reproducible example it's very difficult to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here's how:

- Created an empty, dummy solution inside the directory where the other (third-party) solution is located
- Opened the dummy solution and created two projects:

  - A console app called `ConsoleApp1`
  - A class library called `ClassLibrary1` containing one class called `Class1`
- Referenced `ClassLibrary1` from `ConsoleApp1`, and added code in `Program.Main` referencing `Class1`
- Observed that `Class1` symbol in `ConsoleApp1` was not highlighted and not navigable, similar to my real use case.
- Ensured that my dummy solution builds with no errors.

I then started deleting stuff from the original solution. I thought it might take forever, considering the size of the codebase and the sheer amount of stuff it contains. First I deleted `Directory.Build.props`, `Class1` was still not navigable, though my dummy build was fine. The `Directory.Build.props` file also imports a `Directory.Build.targets` file, so I deleted that as well. Lo and behold, `Class1` lit up in green and became navigable. So then I restored `Directory.Build.targets`, and `Class1` was no longer navigable, and I started deleting various property and item groups from `Directory.Build.targets` until I identified the offending lines:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DisableRoslynDesignTime Condition="...">true</DisableRoslynDesignTime>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It turns out that, because most of the other developers on the project use Resharper, they want to turn off Roslyn at design time because Resharper has it's own analyzer. Since I prefer not to use Resharper, I had disabled it for this particular solution.

There's an [article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/05/11/story-csproj-large-solutions-memory-usage/) which says more about this configuration option.

Comment: Hi, since you have figured it out, you can [mark this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will be helpful to others who meet the similar situation and seeking for the answer. :)